# ServiceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries with SaveChangesOptions.Batch Exception

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to use the batch option to save entities in an azure storage table

Here is the code :

```
foreach (TableEntity entity in entitiesList)
{
     ServiceContext.AddObject(entity.getTableName(), entity);
}

ServiceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
```

I'm getting this Exception :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidInput</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">99:One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:b54a78fe-30ae-427e-86e9-6107d6e3fe5a
Time:2013-01-14T15:50:17.0134794Z</message>
</error>
```

but when I try to to add each entity on a separate query it work's

but what I don't understand is that when I check the table on the azure sotage account with "Azure Storage Explorer", I found the Data that I'm trying to load !!

Can anyone explain why I found the data on the azure table although I have an exception, and how to fix it, in order to use batch option with ServiceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries method

thank's in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch option only supports adding up to 100 entities that have only one PartitionKey.  Please ensure that you're not saving more than 100 entities and that all contain one key.

Please find more information on Batch Entity transactions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> 99:One of the request inputs is not valid.

99 in the above message means that there's an error with 100th entity in your batch (index starting from 0). A few things you could check for:

1. Make sure that the entity data is proper.
2. Since you're performing an "Add" operation, make sure that this entity is not already there. Instead of "Add" operation you could also try **[Insert Or Replace Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452242.aspx)** or **[Insert Or Merge Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452241.aspx)** operation.

Take a look at the following code:

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity()
    {
        PartitionKey = "Customer";
        RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime? LastOrderDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


    static void InsertEntityBatchOperation()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        var cloudTableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        var customer = new CustomerEntity()
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Smith",
            LastOrderDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-10)
        };
        var serviceContext = cloudTableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
        serviceContext.AddObject(tableName, customer);
        customer = new CustomerEntity()
        {
            FirstName = "Jane",
            LastName = "Smith",
            LastOrderDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-5)
        };
        serviceContext.AttachTo(tableName, customer, null);
        serviceContext.UpdateObject(customer);
        customer = new CustomerEntity()
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Doe",
            LastOrderDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-7)
        };
        serviceContext.AttachTo(tableName, customer, null);
        serviceContext.UpdateObject(customer);
        customer = new CustomerEntity()
        {
            FirstName = "Jane",
            LastName = "Doe",
            LastOrderDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-3)
        };
        serviceContext.AttachTo(tableName, customer, null);
        serviceContext.UpdateObject(customer);
        //Following will perform Insert Or Merge Entity Operation
        serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
        //Following will perform Insert Or Replace Entity Operation
        serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch | SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
    }
```